# R Dataframe Group-Level Pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe looks like below:

```
person    year    Office        Job      rank
Harry     2002    Los Angeles   CEO       0
Harry     2006    Boston        CEO       0
Harry     2006    Los Angeles   Advisor   1
Harry     2006    Chicago       Chairman  2

Peter     2001    New York      Director  0
Peter     2001    Chicago       CFO       1
Peter     2002    Chicago       CEO       0

Lily      2005    Springfield   CEO       0
Lily      2007    New York      CFO       0
Lily      2008    Boston        COO       0
Lily      2011    Chicago       Advisor   0
Lily      2011    New York      board     1
```

I want to know at a person level, who has at least one of the following two patterns:

1. in a previous available year, an office has rank 0 and in the next available year, the office still exist but rank is bigger than 0 (job does not matter). For example, Los Angeles for Harry.
2. in a next availabe year, an office has rank 0 and in the previous available year, the office still exist but rank is bigger than 0 (For example, Chicago for Peter).

Note that New York for Lily does not have either of the above situation as 2007 is not the previous available year for Lily (2008 is).

Thus, the output should look like:

```
person    yes/no
Harry     1
Peter     1
Lily      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(person, Office) %>%
   summarise(yes_no =n_distinct(rank) > 1) %>%
   summarise(yes_no = +(any(yes_no)), .groups = 'drop')
```